# MATLAB - Only First Letter of String is Printing

Tags: string, matlab, date, printf

I am having an issue printing a string in MATLAB (2012a) using the `fprtinf` command (and `sprintf`).

I have an array of 12 dates (numeric). I am converting them to strings using the following command:

```
months = datestr(data(:,1)-365,12); %Mar13 format
```

I obtain the following (and desired) output when I call the `months` variable:

Jan12
Feb12
Mar12
Apr12
etc..

The issue is when I call the `fprintf` or `sprintf`, say with the following code:

```
fprintf('%s', months(1))
```

I will only get the first letter of the month and not the full string. Any idea how to make it print the full string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting data type for your `months` variable is an NxM character array. You need to process it as a cell array of strings instead.

```
dates = num2cell(data(:,1)-365)
months = cellfun(@(x) datestr(x,12),dates,'UniformOutput',false)
fprintf('%s', months{1})
```

should get you what you want.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much for the explanation, didnt realize its a character array, havent dealt with that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your call to

```
fprintf('%s', months(1, :))
```

`datestr` returns the string of each of the supplied dates on a separate row.

Alternatively you could use the `cellstr` function to convert the result to a cell array (this would also work with non fixed-length date formats like `'dddd'`)

```
months = cellstr(months);
fprintf('%s', months{1});
```

Comment: Also works, thank you for your quick response. Will adjust my code accordingly.

Comment: Heh, looks like our solutions performed opposite order of operations. :)